# Как реализовать такой диапазон?

Tags: php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, логику реализации такого диапазона в php?
Мне на страницу будут приходить разные наборы чисел, например [5, 40, 100, 500] или [1000, 2000, 5000, 6500]. Как с таких наборов чисел сделать диапазоны как на картинке?

Comment: у вас совсем идей нет никаких?

Comment: Можно было бы картинку в вопросе побольше дать, а то нечего не видно на нем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То есть надо будет сформировать диапазоны. Можно так

```
function diap($num, $diap = array()) {
   $aRes = array();
   if (sizeof($diap) == 0) {
       return $aRes;
   }

   if (sizeof($diap) == 1) {
       return array('< '. $diap[0], '> '.$diap[0]);
   }

   for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($diap); $i++) {
       if ($i == 0) {
           $aRes[] = '< '.$diap[$i];
       } elseif ($i == sizeof($diap) - 1) {
           $aRes[] = '> '.$diap[$i];
       } else {
           $aRes[] = $diap[$i] .' - ' . $diap[$i+1];
       }
   }

   return $aRes;
}
```